# More than one parent activity (Android)

Tags: java, android, android-activity

Helo,

I've got a question.

I've got two activities: Step2_Gdrive.java and Step2_Dropbox.java.

Now I want to start from Step2_Gdrive.java and Step2_Dropbox.java a new activity named Step3.java.

How can i achieve that?

In the android AndroidManifest.xml you can just set up one parent activity:

```
    <activity
        android:name=".Step3"
        android:configChanges="orientation"
        android:label="@string/app_config_step3"
        android:parentActivityName=".Step2_GDrive">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="de.ubik.ueberwachungskamera.Step2_GDrive" />
    </activity>
```

But I want two parent activities, how can I do that?

Comment: Not possible in Java. No multiple inheritance support.

Comment: You cannot `extend` two `activity` in android or java so you cant have two parent activities

Comment: See https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/ancestral.html to understand why two parent activities doesn't make sense.

Comment: @AkshayKatariya A child activity doesn't need to extend the parent activity, but defines a relation used for navigation between activities.

Comment: Its all messed up. now this question isn't making any sense. unclear.

Answer (score -1):

From  activity Step2_Gdrive call

`startActivity(new Intent(Step2_Gdrive.this,Step3.class));`

and from Step2_Dropbox activity call:

```
startActivity(new Intent(Step2_Dropbox.this,Step3.class));
```

Comment: Have you read the question? This is not what OP is asking for. OP wants two parent activities (inheritance).

Comment: he didn't specified inheritance. he said i want to "start" single activity from two activites.

Comment: **But I want two parent activities, how can I do that?**

Comment: @Rohit agreed to what you are saying but what Nouman has answered is also not completely wrong we can navigate to Step3 activity from both Step2_Gdive &  Step2_Dropbox using `intent`

Comment: @Rohit5k2 you are going to fast man. In which perspective i have understand this question i have put my answer accordingly. let us ask OP what he really wants.

Comment: yeah lets wait for it.